# Native window hierarchy and class names in C#

Tags: c#, .net, windows, winapi, spy++

I am creating a function to find specific windows given a window hierarchy as follows:

```
protected bool MapWindowHierarchy (ATS.Library.Window window)
{
    bool result = false;
    List<Process> processes = null;

    processes = GetProcesses().ToList();

    processes.ForEach
    (
        process =>
        {
            if (process.MainWindowHandle == window.Handle)
            {
                // Populate window properties.
                //  Get child windows with filled properties.
            }
        }
    );

    return (result);
}

protected bool MapWindowHierarchy (List<ATS.Library.Window> windows)
{
    return (windows.All(window => this.MapWindowHierarchy(window)));
}

public sealed class Window
{
    public IntPtr Handle { get; set; }
    public string Class { get; set; }
    public Rectangle Bounds { get; set; }
    public Win32Api.User32.ShowWindowCommands WindowState { get; set; }
    public string Caption { get; set; }
    public int Style { get; set; }
    public List<ATS.Library.Window> Windows { get; set; }

    public void PopulateFromHandle(IntPtr hWnd)
    {
        // Populate above properties using Win32 API.
    }
}
```

This is just rough code but the objective is to create a heirarchy using the `[Window]` class and see if the actual hierarchy using `[EnumChildWindows]` matches. This apparently works fine but I came across [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10850485/net-class-name-from-a-window-handle), Hans Passant's comment `"Every unique window in a desktop session must have a unique Windows class name"`, I wasn;t sure how to interpret it (see image below for multiple windows with the same class name). Perhaps what he mentions only applies to managed code (WinForms, WPF, etc.).

Furthermore, I am not sure how to retrieve the class names and text of the windows given I have the handle (hWnd) like Spy++ does (see image below). Notice how the text is retrieved in the tree view but not the `[Find Window]` dialog.

[image: Spy++]

Question:

- Should I be worried about Han's comment since I am only targeting native apps?
- How to get the class name given a window's handle?
- How to get the window text given a window's handle (like in the image)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure why you have to worry.  But yes, these "Button" controls you highlighted in your screenshot are *not* unique windows.  They all look the same and behave the exact same way when you click them.  The only difference is that their text "property" is different.  So they are therefore the exact same window "class".  With "property" and "class" in double-quotes since the winapi is a C api and the C language doesn't support classes or properties.

A window class pre-selects a bunch of properties for a window, you can see them back in the [WNDCLASSEX structur](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633577%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)e, the one you fill in before you call RegisterClassEx().  You then create windows from that, you pass the class name in the CreateWindowEx() winapi call.  The scheme was designed to make it easy to create windows that are similar, much like you use a class in C# to create objects that are similar.  But can still have their own Text property.  And their own Click event handler.

You get the window class name from a handle with the GetClassName() winapi function.

You get the text "property" from a handle with the GetWindowText() winapi function.  GetWindowTextLength() tells you how large a string buffer you need to pass to GetWindowText().

Comment: Thank you for clarifying that Hans. As for the text, notice how the tree view shows it correctly in the image but not the Caption property on the window finder. I'll experiment with GetWindowText but just curious if this function and the Caption property represent something different.

Comment: Not sure what you are talking about.  You've got a dialog selected, not a button.  Using a dialog as an inner window without a border and caption (and not actually implementing a dialog) is a standard trick in unmanaged code, it works well in the native C++ resource editor.  Which is a poor man's version of the Winforms designer.

Comment: I wasn't talking about the button. The value on the Calc screen is 4,294,967,296. Yes, it is the class is a dialog and the tree view shows the value but not the modal window finder. I was wondering why that is so. Since you mention this is a dialog without a Caption, how could you get the text within?

Comment: Just right-click the Static control in the tree and click Properties.  I don't otherwise have any idea why your Finder ended up with the dialog window.  A dialog without a Caption doesn't have any text, it is merely used as a container window for the other child controls, like the buttons.

Comment: That's the problem then. The static control is not being detected by the window finder for some reason even when the mouse is directly over the text. This may have something to do with how Spy++ gets controls from cursor position. I'll use EnumChildWindows to see if I can get to the static control. Thank you.